# play progressive videos that is not safe for streaming on Android

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming

Is there any way to play progressive videos that is not safe for streaming on Android.

What I mean is videos where moov atom is @ end instead of start. iOS n VLC  opens a second connection to find the moov atom. But unfortunately android doesn't.....

Is there a way to make the player do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that this was not possible :(